# Extendend class moving between child methods and parent methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

Just a little easy question

I've extended a class, that is not mine, and I need to use some of the funcs that are into the YamlDataSource

```
class PersistenceDataSource extends YamlDataSource {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._ = this;

    }
```

The problem is that: I need to use a Manager that knows just a bounch of function, for exaplem ***fetchAll***.

So I need it in my ***PersistenceDataSouce*** but I also need to call that one that is implemented into the ***YamlDataSouce***

```
        async fetchAll( config ) { 
//...
            let fetched = this.fetchAll();
            console.log( fetched );
        } );
```

If I do so the fetchAll function into the PersistenceDataSource is fired so I thought to resolve it with the solution that I made into the *constructor*, is it a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `super.METHOD()` the same way you use `super()` to call the constructor.

Hence:

```
async fetchAll(config) {
    super.fetchAll(); // This will call the extended class fetchAll method (YamlDataSource fetchAll) instead of this class one.
});
```